# Linking to OCCI libs generates warnings about std::string

Tags: occi

I have created a Static Library project (sll) which is using the `std::string`. Then I linked it to `oraocci12.lib` (for release) and `oraocci12d.lib` (for debug). And just upon linking the static library to the OCCI ones the project generates many warnings about `std::string`. The warnings are all about **already defined** symbols, something like:

> warning LNK4006: "public: void __cdecl std::basic_string,class std::allocator >::_Copy(unsigned
>   __int64,unsigned __int64)" (?_Copy@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAX_K0@Z)
>   already defined in oraocci12.lib(oraocci12.dll); second definition
>   ignored
>
> warning LNK4006: "public: char * __cdecl std::_Wrap_alloc >::allocate(unsigned __int64)"
>   (?allocate@?$_Wrap_alloc@V?$allocator@D@std@@@std@@QEAAPEAD_K@Z)
>   already defined in oraocci12.lib(oraocci12.dll); second definition
>   ignored
>
> warning LNK4006: "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > & __cdecl
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >::assign(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,unsigned
>   __int64,unsigned __int64)" (?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@AEBV12@_K1@Z)
>   already defined in oraocci12.lib(oraocci12.dll); second definition
>   ignored
>
> warning LNK4006: "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > & __cdecl
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >::assign(char const *,unsigned __int64)"
>   (?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@PEBD_K@Z)
>   already defined in oraocci12.lib(oraocci12.dll); second definition
>   ignored
>
> warning LNK4006: "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > & __cdecl
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >::erase(unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64)"
>   (?erase@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@_K0@Z)
>   already defined in oraocci12.lib(oraocci12.dll); second definition
>   ignored
>
> warning LNK4006: "`string'"
>   (??_C@_0BA@JFNIOLAK@string?5too?5long?$AA@) already defined in
>   oraocci12.lib(oraocci12.dll); second definition ignored
>
> warning LNK4006: "`string'"
>   (??_C@_0BI@CFPLBAOH@invalid?5string?5position?$AA@) already defined in
>   oraocci12.lib(oraocci12.dll); second definition ignored

I have tried changing the:

- **Platform Toolset** in *Project Properties => General*.
- **Character Set** in *Project Properties => General*.
- **Runtime Library** in *Project Properties => C/C++ => Code Generation*.
- **Verbose** in *Project Properties => Librarian => General*.
- **Ignore All default Libraries** in *Project Properties => Librarian => General*.

Also tried linking to different oracle libs:

- msvc\vc14\oraocci12.lib (release)
- msvc\vc14\oraocci12d.lib (debug)
- msvc\oraocci12.lib (release)
- msvc\oraocci12d.lib (debug)

I have also tried many combinations of the above, but the problem persists.

IMP: It happens if the project type is `sll`. If it is changed to `dll`, then the warnings go away.

> Environment details:
>
> - Visual Studio Professional 2017 (15.6.7)
> - Project Type is Static Library (sll, x64)
> - Windows 10
> - Oracle **instantclient-sdk-windows.x64-12.2.0.1.0**

Thanks all!